# Retrieve URI attached to ClientResource

Tags: restlet, restlet-2.0

When I create a new ClientResource, I usually do the following

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("URI string");
```

Is there a way to recover the URI string later in time from `cr`?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some additional hints about this issue:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource("http://www.google.fr:8182/test");

String hostDomain = cr.getReference().getHostDomain();
String hostIdentifier = cr.getReference().getHostIdentifier();
int hostPort = cr.getReference().getHostPort();
String path = cr.getReference().getPath();
String scheme = cr.getReference().getScheme();

System.out.println("hostIdentifier = "+hostIdentifier);
System.out.println("hostDomain = "+hostDomain);
System.out.println("scheme = "+scheme);
System.out.println("hostPort = "+hostPort);
System.out.println("path = "+path);
```

This will give you the following:

```
hostIdentifier = http://www.google.fr:8182
hostDomain = www.google.fr
scheme = http
hostPort = 8182
path = /test
```

You can notice that, if the port isn't explicitely specified in the URL, the value of `hostDomain` is `-1`.

Hope it helps,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution testing some get method.
You can use `CLientResource#getReference`, inherited from the abstract class `Resource`.
It returns a `Reference` object that is a

> Reference to a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI). Contrary to the
>   java.net.URI class, this interface represents mutable references. It
>   strictly conforms to the RFC 3986 specifying URIs and follow its
>   naming conventions. [...]
>
> The fundamental point to underline is the difference between an URI
>   "reference" and an URI. Contrary to an URI (the target identifier of a
>   REST resource), an URI reference can be relative (with or without
>   query and fragment part). This relative URI reference can then be
>   resolved against a base reference via the getTargetRef() method which
>   will return a new resolved Reference instance, an absolute URI
>   reference with no base reference and with no dot-segments (the path
>   segments "." and "..").

See [here](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.1/jee/api/org/restlet/resource/Resource.html#getReference()) and [here](http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.1/jee/api/org/restlet/data/Reference.html) for more infos.